# Rails - can I call a controller method from my ActionCable coffeescript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm building a quiz app that leads all participants synchroneously through multiple stages:

1. Phase 0: Quiz has not started
2. Phase 1: Current question is being displayed
3. Phase 3: Result for current question (correct answer vs given answer, statistics etc.) is being displayed
4. Phase 4: Result for entire quiz is being displayed

**If a participant loses his connection and reconnects, I want them to be able to immediately pick up where they left off.**

I always save the current phase to the db. So I'm thinking of calling a method `show_current_phase(curent_user)` in the `connected` method of my ActionCable channel. Since I feel like it would make sense to place this method in the corresponding controller for my custom QuizSession model, I'd like to know:

**Is it possible to call a controller method in my coffeescript (frontend)** and have it return an object?

Or how do I update the DOM tree of only the user who reconnected without broadcasting to all the other participants?

Answer (score 0):

You can just turning your `.coffee` file into an `.haml` or `.erb` template.

#### .erb example with js

```
# myscript.js
var myPath = '/some_path';
```

Will become

```
# myscript.js.erb
var myPath = <%= some_controller_path %> ;
```

#### .haml example with coffee

In case you are using *haml*, the process is not really different.

```
# myscript.coffee
myPath = '/some_path'
```

Will become

```
# myscript.coffee.haml
myPath = '#{ some_controller_path }'
```

Obviously, you can create `.js.haml` and `.coffee.erb` files as well.

In your case, you could have something like this in your `.coffee.haml`:

```
myFunction = ->
  res = $.ajax(
    url: '#{method_controller_path}'
    method: 'GET'
    data:
      variableParam: '#{@my_controller_var}'
      anotherParam: 'anotherParam'
    dataType: 'json'
    success: (res) ->
      res
  )
  doSomething res
```